# The angle $\theta$ of the prism is

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, geometric-optics

[image]

A parallel beam of light is incident from air at an angle $a$ on the side $PQ$ of a right angled triangular prism of refractive index $n = \sqrt{2}$. 
Light undergoes total internal reflection in the prism at the face $PR$ when $a$ has a minimum value of $45°$. The angle $\theta$ of the prism is ...

Snell's law is given by

$$n_1 \sin \theta_1 = n_2 \sin \theta_2$$

However, I'm not sure about the equation and the way we need to follow. Can you brighten me up?

Comment: Can you draw the path of the light inside the prism? What is the condition for total internal reflection?

Comment: Yes, I drew it. What do you mean by internal reflection?

Comment: The question states "light undergoes total internal reflection at PR". Do you know what that means?

Comment: No, First time I've heard it. I currently don't have any idea about what total internal reflection at $PR$ means.

Comment: I have written an answer with the diagram that should help. Review your notes, or google "total internal reflection", if that is still not clear enough.

Comment: @Floris I'm gonna try on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the diagram you need:

[image]

The critical angle $\alpha_c$ is the one at which you just get total internal reflection - that is, the transmitted light would make an angle of 90° to the normal. That means that $\sin\alpha_c = \frac{n_1}{n_2}$.

That should be the hint that gets you going...